# Visual Studio 2005 solution doesn't show visual studio icon

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, windows-server-2012-r2

I installed Visual Studio 2005 in Windows 2012 R2 server. The visual studio 2005 setup got installed after bunch of compatibility warning. I got the source code from VSS and while viewing the solution, it looks like it is missing visual studio icon. Does anyone know how to get it back?

See the screenshot one with missing solution icon and other with one.
Thanks

[image]

**Update: Here is how i fixed it. Right click the solution file > Properties > Click change button on 'Open with' and navigate to D:\Program Files(86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe**

Answer (score -1):

Open Visual Studio then File -> Open Project -> and search .sln file

Comment: That works but I want to be able to see icon with version # i.e. 8 as in screenshot.

Comment: Sometimes this occurs, try to re-install Visual Studio. But it is necessary to delete all the files associated with Visual Studio from the Windows registry.

Comment: Try to install Visual Studio 2017 community, it's free

Comment: i have 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013 already installed. :) Don't think that will fix it.

Comment: @yakobom what button??